# Como abrir un perfil de instagram en un webView, para Android con Android Studio?

Tags: android, instagram

Estoy desarrollando un ejercicio que implementa un Navigation Drawer a partir de la plantilla que tiene Android Studio y la vengo modificando y colocando funcionalidades a los botones del menú.

Uno de mis botones direcciona a un perfil de Instagram, lo que yo quiero es que nunca se salga de mi aplicación y muestre el perfil de instagram en el contenido principal de mi NavigationDrawer, pero actualmente aunque estoy tratándolo como un webView sigue abriendo con el navegador predeterminado del dispositivo, no sé si es necesario usar algunas Apis especiales de instagram; a continuación les muestro el cógigo en el Fragment que agrega la funcionalidad al botón. agradezco su ayuda.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String url="aquí va la url";
    WebView view=(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wvinstagram);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

De esta manera lo que hace es abrir el perfil con el navegador, intenté en el método onCreateView de la siguiente manera y la aplicación se cierra,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram,container,false);

    String url="aquí coloco la url";
    WebView v =(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wvinstagram);
    v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    v.loadUrl(url);

    return view;
}
```

Anulo la fracción de código para el WebView y se ejecuta normalmente sin contenido.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram,container,false);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que asignar el cliente web antes de cargar la url para evitar que te abra el navegador:

```
WebView v =(WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.wvinstagram);
v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
v.setWebViewClient(new WebChromeClient());
v.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.